# Running rails core tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I'd like to make a contribution to the rails project, but am stumbling at the first hurdle...
I've cloned the rails repository and am getting an error when trying to run the unit tests.

```
$ bundle exec rake test
...
/home/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/spec.rb:131:in `register_spec_type': wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) (ArgumentError)
```

I'm using:

- rvm with ruby ruby-1.9.3-preview1 (1.9.2 told me there was an incompatibility with rails 4)
- rake-0.9.2.2
- latest github commit tried: 211174a
- (ubuntu)

Just to double check:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3dev (2011-07-31 revision 32789) [i686-linux]
```

I've read and did not find any info in http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html

Have also completely reinstalled rvm, recompiled ruby, and replaced all gems multiple times.

Comment: Have you tried with the stable release of 1.9.3?

Comment: @Beerlington you're right - it works with 1.9.3 stable. rvm installed the preview version by default. Tests all pass except one - test_really_long_keys(FileStoreTest) but I'll take a look at that later. If you write your answer out, I'll accept it. I think rails should really say that 1.9.3 stable is a requirement. I don't see that info anywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The master branch of Rails is now the [beta version for 4.0.0](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/12/20/rails-master-is-now-4-0-0-beta) and removes support for Ruby 1.8.7. I don't know exactly why it doesn't work with Ruby 1.9.3 preview, but I would recommend always running with the latest **stable** version of Ruby. Another option is to try running the tests in Ruby 1.9.2 and see if you get any errors.

Comment: 1.9.3 stable works, but I already tried 1.9.2 stable with no luck.

Comment: You can always check travis-ci.org to see the current build status of Rails. http://travis-ci.org/#!/rails/rails